# Analysis of contingency table with ordinal outcome?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, ordinal-data, contingency-tables

What statistical test do I apply in following 2 situations:

```
Three drugs are tested on 3 groups of subjects.
Outcome variable is ordinal (degree of improvement): 0,1,2,3 (none, mild, moderate, marked)

Study 1: Subjects for 3 drug groups are different (parallel study design)
Study 2: Same set of subjects take 3 drugs one by one (crossover design)
```

Aim is to determine if one drug causes more improvements than other 2.

I think I will have to apply regression. But can I use linear regression here? Do I have to use mixed models with ordinal outcomes to account for repeated measures in the second study.

Which test do I apply for each study?

Comment: Search this site for *ordinal regression*.